# Вылет программы сортировки при длине массива более 128000 элементов

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, сортировка

Возникла проблема в программе сортировки слиянием. Исходный массив, заполненный случайными числами, "разбивается" на два подмассива, каждый из которых сортируется отдельно(если в исходном массиве более 5000 элементов, то используется сортировка выбором, если меньше - гномья сортировка) и потом они сливаются в результирующий массив. Проблема заключается в том, что если задать длину массива больше 128 000, то программа вылетает.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int length = 128000;
int arr1[length];
int i;

for (i = 0; i<length; i++)
{
    arr1[i] = (rand() % 99)+1;
    cout << arr1[i] << " ";
}

int counter1, counter2, counter3; //array's counters

counter1 = 0; //не больше (length-2)/2
counter2 = length / 2; //не больше length-1
counter3 = 0; //не больше length-1

if (length>5000)
{   
    int j, k;
    int number;//the number of the maximum element
    int maximum;//the maximum element

    for (j = counter1; j <= (length - 2) / 2; j++)
    {
        maximum = arr1[j];
        number = j;
        for (k = j + 1; k <= (length - 2) / 2 - 1; k++)
        {
            if (maximum>arr1[k])
            {
                maximum = arr1[k];
                number = k;
            }
        }
        swap(arr1[j], arr1[number]);
    }

    for (j = counter2; j <= length - 2; j++)
    {
        maximum = arr1[j];
        number = j;

        for (k = j + 1; k <= length - 1; k++)
        {
            if (maximum>arr1[k])
            {
                maximum = arr1[k];
                number = k;
            }
        }
        swap(arr1[j], arr1[number]);
    }
}
else
{
    int j = counter1;

    while (j<(length - 2) / 2 + 1)
    {
        if (j == 0 || arr1[j - 1] <= arr1[j])
            j++;
        else
        {
            swap(arr1[j], arr1[j - 1]);
            j--;
        }
    }

    int k = counter2;

    while (k<length)
    {
        if (k == 0 || arr1[k - 1] <= arr1[k])
            k++;
        else
        {
            swap(arr1[k], arr1[k - 1]);
            k--;
        }
    }
}

int arr2[length];
int l;

while (counter3 != length)
{
    if (arr1[counter1] <= arr1[counter2])
    {
        arr2[counter3] = arr1[counter1];
        counter1++;
        if (counter1 == (length - 2) / 2 + 1)
        {
            counter3++;
            for (l = counter2; l <= length - 1; l++)
            {
                arr2[counter3] = arr1[l];
                counter3++;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        arr2[counter3] = arr1[counter2];
        counter2++;
        if (counter2 == length)
        {
            counter3++;
            for (l = counter1; l <= (length - 2) / 2; l++)
            {
                arr2[counter3] = arr1[l];
                counter3++;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    counter3++;
}

int s;

cout << "\n";

for (s = 0; s <= length - 1; s++)
    cout<< arr2[s];
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Зачем здесь тэг [C]?

Answer (score 5):

Краткий ответ - 128000*4 = а это пол мегабайта.

Ваш массив выделяется на стеке, а стек в большинстве современных систем - обычно не больше 1 мегабайта на поток. Хотите больше - используйте `std::vector<int>`.

Очень похоже, что заменив строку

```
int arr1[length];
```

на

```
std::vector<int> arr1(length);
```

и добавив в самый верх `#include <vector>`, все будет работать.

Но можно конечно выделять память через malloc/new. Но это и не модно, и требует существенной переделки программы.